# How to implement ease BounceOut (Elastic) functionality in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to implement a bounce out easing function in my application.

Something similar to elastic out.

Like as in the following link
http://www.powerping.be/js/jstween/moveSquare.html

I want to implement something like that.

Comment: You don't really have enough information here.  In what context do you want to want to do this?  There are all sorts of conditions you could be talking about: animations in UIView context, Quartz2D, OpenGL ES, etc.

Comment: Any examples of what you tried?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, so I'm guessing you're trying to animate a UIView (or similar) using Core Animation.

You'll want to look at using `CABasicAnimation`, which provides a mechanism for animating properties (like position), as well as setting a timing function (or "easing function") via the `timingFunction` property.

The `timingFunction` property takes an instance of `CAMediaTimingFunction`, which has a number of [predefined timing functions](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Predefined_Timing_Functions) like `kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear`, `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn`, `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut` & `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut`. If the predefined functions aren't enough, you can define your own which is described in the [Animation Types and Timing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Introduction/Introduction.html) (in particular, the section on [Animation Pacing](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006670-DontLinkElementID_10)).

The next step up from `CABasicAnimation` is `CAKeyframeAnimation`, which you may need to do if you want to animate your view along a multi-segment path, with a separate timing functions per path segment. There are some examples on how that works under [Keyframe Timing and Pacing Extensions](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/PropertyAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006672-SW7).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I thought CoreAnimation was only available for osx, thanks for this!